# ¿Se puede ordenar una tabla por las últimas filas modificadas en mysql?

Tags: mysql

Necesito cambiar los últimos registros que modifiqué en una tabla y la única manera de saber cuáles eran es esa misma, que fueron los últimos que modifiqué.

Comment: No se puede a menos que tengas un backup de la tabla o hayas guardado la fecha de modificación de las filas en la misma tabla

Comment: Si lo que quieres es encontrar qué registros se han modificado accidentalmente para recuperar su valor anterior prueba con mi respuesta. Gracias a las herramientas de análisis del log binario he podido recuperar algunas modificaciones erróneas. Pero el log binario por defecto sólo guarda 100M, así que deberás darte prisa antes de que se "machaque" la información que buscas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias respuestas dependiendo de cómo de flexible puede ser la solución que buscas:

- Con una consulta SQL y sin modificar el esquema de la tabla: NO se puede.
- Con una consulta SQL agregando un campo que se actualice al modificar el registro: Se puede.
- Con iniciadores (triggers) sin modificar el esquema de la tabla, pero con una tabla nueva relacionada donde se almacene dicha información: Se puede.
- Con herramientas externas: Se puede analiza el log binario en busca de las últimas modificaciones.

La más sencilla de implementar es cambiar el esquema de tu tabla y agregar un campo de [última modificación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

Para agregar un campo `ultima_modificacion` sin perder los datos previos puedes usar:

```
ALTER TABLE
  tabla
ADD COLUMN
  ultima_modificacion DATETIME(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

El tipo `DATETIME(6)` guarda la fecha y hora con una [resolución de microsegundos](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html).

La consulta sería:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla
WHERE ...
ORDER BY
  ultima_modificacion DESC
```

Usar iniciadores que guarden datos de actualización en una tabla adicional evitaría que cambiaras el esquema de tu tabla, pero supondría un esfuerzo adicional y una sobrecarga para la base de datos innecesaria.

Usar una herramienta de análisis de log binario es complejo y tiene un límite impuesto por el tamaño del log binario. No se pueden conocer las modificaciones realizadas más allá del momento en el que se rotaron todos los logs.

Puedes consultar el funcionamiento de una herramienta de este tipo (no es la única) aquí: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlbinlog-row-events.html

```
shell> mysqlbinlog -v --base64-output=DECODE-ROWS log_file
...
# at 218
#080828 15:03:08 server id 1  end_log_pos 258   Write_rows: table id 17 flags: STMT_END_F
### INSERT INTO test.t
### SET
###   @1=1
###   @2='apple'
###   @3=NULL
...
# at 302
#080828 15:03:08 server id 1  end_log_pos 356   Update_rows: table id 17 flags: STMT_END_F
### UPDATE test.t
### WHERE
###   @1=1
###   @2='apple'
###   @3=NULL
### SET
###   @1=1
###   @2='pear'
###   @3='2009:01:01'
```

Comment: Gracias Óscar, lo probaré.

Comment: ¡Suerte con ello! 

Answer (score 0):

No.
Lo que puedes hacer es agregar un campo con la fecha de registro y ordenar los registros a partir del valor de esa fecha.